# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm parsing some data using a type class in my controller. I'm getting data as follows:

```
{  
   "data": {  
      "userList":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"soni"
         }
      ]
   },
   "status":200,
   "config":{  
      "method":"POST",
      "transformRequest":[  
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[  
         null
      ],
      "url":"/home/main/module/userlist",
      "headers":{  
         "rt":"ajax",
         "Tenant":"Id:null",
         "Access-Handler":"Authorization:null",
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
   },
  

   "statusText":"OK"
}
```

I tried to store the data like this

```
var userData = _data;
var newData = JSON.parse(userData).data.userList;
```

How can I extract the user list to a new variable?

Comment: You may need not use `JSON.parse`. Try using `userData` directly as an object.

Comment: If `console.log(typeof userData)` shows `object` then you already have an javascript object and not a JSON string you need to parse.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj yes, need not required for the parse..

Comment: Usually whenever you get this error - `Unexpected token o in JSON`, most probably you are trying to parse an object which is already in parsed form.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj  okay!

Comment: Data is already in JSON format, No need to covert it or parse it.

Comment: JavaScript? More like WeirdScript.

Answer (score 564, accepted):

The JSON you posted looks fine, however in your code, it is most likely not a JSON string anymore, but already a JavaScript object. This means, no more parsing is necessary.

You can test this yourself, e.g. in Chrome's console:

```
new Object().toString()
// "[object Object]"

JSON.parse(new Object())
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

JSON.parse("[object Object]")
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

`JSON.parse()` converts the input into a string. The `toString()` method of JavaScript objects by default returns `[object Object]`, resulting in the observed behavior.

**Try the following instead:**

```
var newData = userData.data.userList;
```

Comment: So it this applicable for all kinds of browsers ?

Comment: @Timo Could you look this link.

Comment: Sometimes this error can surface when the api url endpoint that serves the request has an error in its code or some other included or used file and it throws a error which is not  handled or noted. Mostly you can get this if you look at the network tab in Browser developer tools or you can hit the endpoint using post man and see what comes up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the JSON String vs JS Obj distinction, easier to remember how to do it right when you know why it happened.

Comment: Saved me a few minutes, thanks.  I was using require.

Comment: In express I was doing JSON.parse(response.data) which I had forgot was already parsed into json object hence causing this error.

Answer (score 217):

The first parameter of the `JSON.parse` function is expected to be a string, and your data is a JavaScript object, so it will coerce it to the string `"[object Object]"`. You should use `JSON.stringify` before passing the data:

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData))
```

Comment: this will not work when the string contains a double quote  do you have any solution

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why would you turn an object into JSON (which is what `JSON.stringify()` does), only to parse the JSON back into an object? Why not use the object directly? This seems completely superfluous.

Comment: Probably not the example from the OP - but sometimes you need the JSON structure and not JavaScript one for some libraries. This helped.

Comment: If you need JSON then you **wouldn't** use `JSON.parse` since that turns the JSON back into JS.

Answer (score 51):

Don't ever use `JSON.parse` without wrapping it in `try-catch` block:

```
// payload 
let userData = null;

try {
    // Parse a JSON
    userData = JSON.parse(payload); 
} catch (e) {
    // You can read e for more info
    // Let's assume the error is that we already have parsed the payload
    // So just return that
    userData = payload;
}

// Now userData is the parsed result
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, but comments on lack of exception handling.

Comment: @RichardDuerr, but this will helps to fix error of head topic. 
i.e. SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: That merely hides the error, but not actually solve it.

Answer (score 28):

Just above `JSON.parse`, use:

```
var newData = JSON.stringify(userData)
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` converts a JavaScript object to a string representation of it, which is the opposite of what `JSON.parse()` does. You were getting the `SyntaxError` because you were trying to parse something that was already an object. In @Sukhchain's solution, it gets converted to a string to avoid that.

Comment: The downside of that is, in the end you're using `JSON.parse()` too much redundantly. Even though it's a pretty fast process, parsing JSON is done synchronously and can potentially block your UI, so I'd advise against using that. Instead, you could check if your variable is an object, for example using `typeof(userData) ===  'object'` before attempting to parse it.

Answer (score 13):

We can also add checks like this:

```
function parseData(data) {
    if (!data) return {};
    if (typeof data === 'object') return data;
    if (typeof data === 'string') return JSON.parse(data);

    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply check the `typeof userData` & `JSON.parse()` it only if it's `string`:

```js
var userData = _data;
var newData;
if (typeof userData === 'object')
  newData = userData.data.userList; // dont parse if its object
else if (typeof userData === 'string')
  newData = JSON.parse(userData).data.userList; // parse if its string
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the error is Object is not in the form of string, it is `{}` and it should be string Object(`'{}'`)

Answer (score 3):

**Unexpected 'O' error is thrown when JSON data or String happens to get parsed.**

**If it's string, it's already stringfied. Parsing ends up with Unexpected 'O' error.**

I faced similar( although in different context), I solved the following error by removing JSON Producer.

```
    @POST
    @Produces({ **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON**})
    public Response login(@QueryParam("agentID") String agentID , Officer aOffcr ) {
      return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();

  }
```

The response contains **"OK"** string return. 
The annotation marked as **@Produces({ **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON**})** tries to parse the string to JSON format which results in *Unexpected 'O'*.

Removing *@Produces({ **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON**})* works fine.
Output : **OK**

Beware:
Also, on client side, if you make ajax request and use JSON.parse("OK"), it throws Unexpected token 'O'

**O** is the first letter of the string

JSON.parse(object) compares with jQuery.parseJSON(object);

JSON.parse('{ "name":"Yergalem", "city":"Dover"}');   --- Works Fine

Answer (score -1):

Give a try catch like this, this will parse it if its stringified or else will take the default value

```
let example;
   try {
   example  = JSON.parse(data)
  } catch(e) {
    example = data
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

First set request value in variable like:

```js
let reqData = req.body.reqData;
if (reqData) {
  let reqDataValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reqData));
}
```