# How do I access status code from response headers of a HEAD request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to access the status code for the HEAD request. How do I access the same?

```
  getNameObj(queryStr: string): Promise<any> {
   return this.http.head(endpoints.getNamesUrl(queryStr))
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleResponse(response: HttpResponseBase): Promise<any> {
    console.log(response.status)
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error);
   }
```

Alos, I am getting an error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1...`

Comment: If you search for the error message with your preferred search provider you will get a _huge_ load of answers.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1