# Why it works like this?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm novice in javascript and iI don't understand this error.

```
 VM1274:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: can you include the JSON that your code is trying to parse?

Comment: It means the JSON you are trying to parse is not valid

Comment: Most likely, a property name or value in your json has not been enclosed in double quotes. But we need the JSON to figure out the actual error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1)