# Create and Read JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

1. I created a JSON file as follows

```
{
    
"fooditems" : [
        {
            "name": "pizza",
        "type": "fastfood",
        "price": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "apple",
        "type": "fruit",
        "price": 1
        }
    ]

}
```

2. created a JS file to read the JSON file

```
const data = require("./data.json");
    
data1 = JSON.parse(data);

data1.foodData.forEach( foodItem => console.log(foodItem));
```

3. When I run the JS, I get error for the json file

Syntax error: Unexpected token o in json at position 1
at JSON.parse

Comment: log the contents of `data` to the console before you try to parse it and check what it really looks like. Usually this error is because the data is in fact already an object (rather than a string), and therefore doesn't need parsing. `require` already treats it as an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse `data` since it's already and object. The following should work.

```
const data = require("./data.json");
data.fooditems.forEach( foodItem => console.log(foodItem));
```

Note `foodData` was change to `fooditems` based on the contents of the data.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial data JSON contains "fooditems", but in the JS file you are trying to process the "foodData". Change the "foodData" to "fooditems" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to access invalid object key in your JS file on the last line.

Instead of
`data1.foodData`
put
`data1.fooditems`