# Trying to add key/value to JSON object from TOML file. Why does it fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

Can someone figure out, why I get this error when I try to append a key/value to this JSON object?

```
$ node t.js 
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

**t.js**

```
const toml = require('./toml');
const moment = require('moment');    
const t = toml('./non-production.toml');

let a = new Object;
a = JSON.parse(t.Jira.pack.c);

const time = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
a["customfield_11904"] = time;

console.log(JSON.parse(a));
```

**toml.js**

```
const TOML = require('@iarna/toml');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (filename) => {
  return TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
}
```

**non-production.toml**

```
[Jira]
  pack.c = '{ "project": { "key": "DEMO" }, "issuetype": { "id": 10002 }, "priority": { "id": "3" }}'
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` is for strings not objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1)

Comment: A simple search on the error message on Stack Overflow found that duplicate very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is an object and cannot be parsed with `JSON.parse`, use `console.log(a)` instead