# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 only in Chrome

Tags: webpack, node-modules, mern, unexpected-token

I am having this error when I run my MERN application but it **only** appears in Google Chrome, in Safari I can run it perfectly.

[image]

It seems that it's not reading localStorage correctly and it gets some values as undefined.

I really have no clue about the reason of this problem because it had never happened before and I've been working on this same app for months. I did install and uninstall some things because I was having a strange and sudden error, but I don't see how it can be related to this particular error.
I'll be entirely grateful if someone could help me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess this is what you're running into: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38380728/5818684

You must be trying to parse an object, and JSON.parse converts it into a string, which can't be parsed by it.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I erased the JSON.parse and run it again, it worked!! Now I wrote it back and it's still working. Maybe there was something kind of stuck.. I don't know. But thanks again! :)