# Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 OR Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was looking at this post: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1#)

Exactly my issue.
But when I try to remove the parse, I then get the error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Here is my original excerpt:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getuser.php",
        data: 'person='+str,
        success: function(response){
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            var data = result.rows;
                $("#id").val(data[0].id);
                $("#card").val(data[0].card);
                $("#name").val(data[0].name);
                $("#type").val(data[0].type);
                $("#cabin").val(data[0].cabin);
                $("#birthdate").val(data[0].birthdate);
        }
    });
```

My incoming data from getuser.php is:

```
{"id":"16758","card":"221","name":"Spongebob","type":"Staff","cabin":"24","town":"Bikini Bottom","birthdate":"07/14/1986"}
```

So if I remove the parse and make it:

```
success: function(response){
            var data = response.rows;
```

It gives me the property 0 of undefined.

Here is a fiddle excluding the request from php: http://jsfiddle.net/vzwbop2t/

Any ideas?
I am looking to edit a user, so I need the database values to populate the inputs in the form, so then any modifications, and it's saved back to the user.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(response);`?  If your endpoint sets the `content-type: application/json` header, then jQuery may've parsed the data for you into an object already.  This is the case in the jsfiddle example.  The `response` is _already_ an object and doesn't need to be `JSON.parse`d.

Comment: Also, there is no `rows` array in your data.  That is just a single object, no arrays.  So, you may just need `$("#id").val(response.id);`

Comment: Rocket, you are correct, I was overlooking it wasn't a set of rows for once!  It is working without the rows breakdown.  Put that in as an answer to get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery's `$.ajax`, it checks the `content-type` header returned by the server.  If it's set to `application/json`, then it runs `JSON.parse()` for you.

This means your `response` may *already* be an object (and not a string that needs to be "parsed").

Also, your data is a *single* object, not an array of objects, there is no `row` property/array.  You just need to use `$("#id").val(response.id);`, etc.