# Next.js Puppeteer PDF Downloadable link returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, next.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in my Next.js backend routes to generate a PDF from a given URL.
After that I return that pdf to automatically download that PDF from my client.

Currently I get this error from my PDF output:

> VM640:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON
> at position 0

My PDF output looks similar to this:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
```

This is the backend part, in which I use puppeteer to generate my PDF:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

async function printPdf(req, res) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(`http://localhost:3000/real-estate-pdf/${req.body.slug}`, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  })
  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    path: 'test.pdf',
    printBackground: true,
    format: 'a4',
  })
  await browser.close()

  return pdf
}

async function generatePdf(req, res) {
  const pdf = await printPdf(req, res)

  res.send(pdf)
}

export default generatePdf
```

And this is the frontend part to receive the PDF data and to start a download:

Call the api route:

```
const create = async () => {
    const pdfCall = await fetch('/api/pdf', {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        slug: fileName.split('.')[0],
      }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      method: 'POST',
    })
    const { error } = await pdfCall.json()
    console.log('error: ' + error)
}
```

This is how I try to generate the automatic PDF download:

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(data)
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen)
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
      var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i)
      bytes[i] = ascii
    }
    return bytes
}

function clientPdfDownload(base64Data) {
    var arrBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Data)

    // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type explicitly set
    // otherwise only Chrome works like it should
    var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: 'application/pdf' })

    // IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
    // instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob)
      return
    }

    // For other browsers:
    // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
    var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob)

    var link = document.createElement('a')
    document.body.appendChild(link) //required in FF, optional for Chrome
    link.href = data
    link.download = 'file.pdf'
    link.click()
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data)
    link.remove()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1)